# componentResized Listener not working with setIcon()

Tags: java, swing, icons

I try to make the background fit JLabel when window resizing , i have a problem with componentResized because is not working when I use setIcon().
 it's fine when the window becomes bigger, but it's stopped working when reduce the size of the window and all elements starts to disappear until I expand it again.

here is my code ...

```
public class EntranceContent extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ComponentListener {
      ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(EntranceContent.class.getResource("../background_images/Smartphone-wallpapers.jpg")));
      Image image1;
      Image image2;
      ImageIcon  image3;

      int height;
      int width;
    /**
     * Creates new form EnteryContent
     */
    public EntranceContent() {
        initComponents();


       Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
       Dimension dim= new Dimension(tool.getScreenSize());
       height=dim.height-50;
       width=dim.width;
       this.setSize(width,height);
       this.setLocation(width/2- getWidth() /2 , height/2- getHeight()/2);

       content_jpanel.addComponentListener(this);



    }

@Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {

            //contentHolder is JLabel

                 contentHolder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (content_jpanel.getWidth(), content_jpanel.getHeight()));    

                image1=image.getImage();
                image2=image1.getScaledInstance(contentHolder.getWidth(), contentHolder.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);


                image3=new ImageIcon(image2); 
  //  contentHolder.setIcon(image3);  // not work because of this line 


    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ce) {

      //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ce) {


    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent ce) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We don't know the context of the code you posted, for example what layout managers you are using. 2) You can check out the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will do the resizing of the Icon automatically

Comment: One way to get image(s) for an example (as mentioned by @camickr) is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: @camickr  the stretch icon solved the problem , Thank you ^^